# computer vision transformers: ViT does not have a decoder?

Tags: computer-vision, transformer, attention-mechanism

[image: videopic]

from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrdevFK_am4 that explains the paper titled, "AN IMAGE IS WORTH 16X16 WORDS:
TRANSFORMERS FOR IMAGE RECOGNITION AT SCALE"

compare that to the architecture shown here https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/

So the ViT has a simpler architecture?  It seems like the output of the encoder is the input to the MLP for the classification tasks.

Also I was referred to this repo https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch for learning purposes.

Are there any other ones I should know about?

I took a computational photography class at GaTech OMSCS (my specialization says robotics and computational perception) but that was in 2019 so I need to do some catching up, not to mention computer vision is different from photography.

Please feel free to link to additional resources which I should be going through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the task you want to perform. The goal here is to find a way to represent your image as a sequence of embedding vectors representing each patch of the image
Once you have obtained an encoded representation of your input image, you can

- perform image classification adding a classification head (i.e a few linear layers, as shown in the picture). Here's an example image classification with ViT on [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/tasks/image_classification)
- generate new sequences of images or text (e.g adding a GPT decoder which takes the sequence of hidden states and outputs a sequence of tokens for tasks like image captioning, visual question answering ...). Here's an example of image captioning on [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/tasks/image_captioning). VQA is quite similar, only requiring to pass to the decoder a representation of the image and the question as text.

Comment: I have some experience with transfer learning ResNet50 for classification but can you post some links to tutorials for both points you mention if there are any?  Especially number 2.

Comment: I've added an example for both cases. Anyways, the main message is that once you have found a clever way to represent an image as a sequence of encoded patches, then you can apply any Sequence Classification / Seq2Seq task you like, just like with text.

Answer (score 1):

I prompted ChatGPT and received a good response including a link to https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/12/transformers-for-image-recognition-at.html

Prompt:

> Please link to some implementation examples and tutorials, including
> Hugging Face, for the paper titled AN IMAGE IS WORTH 16X16 WORDS:
> TRANSFORMERS FOR IMAGE RECOGNITION AT SCALE so I can learn more about
> it.

Response:

> Here are some example implementations and tutorials for the paper "AN
> IMAGE IS WORTH 16X16 WORDS: TRANSFORMERS FOR IMAGE RECOGNITION AT
> SCALE":
>
> 1. Hugging Face's official implementation of the ViT model in PyTorch:    https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/vision
> 2. TensorFlow's official implementation of the ViT model:    https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer
> 3. A tutorial on how to use the ViT model in TensorFlow:    https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_with_vision_transformer/
> 4. A tutorial on using the ViT model to classify images in PyTorch:    https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-for-image-recognition-61527a2fed19
> 5. A blog post discussing the paper and its implications:    https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/12/transformers-for-image-recognition-at.html
> 6. A YouTube video explaining the paper and its key ideas:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrdevFK_am4

That was my second prompt because I knew Hugging Face had one which was missing from the first prompt's response:

> 1. Official Implementation by authors: https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer
> 2. PyTorch implementation by Ross Wightman: https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/tree/master/timm/models/vision_transformer
> 3. TensorFlow implementation by Piotr Dollar: https://github.com/pdollar/coco/tree/master/PythonAPI/pycocotools
> 4. Keras implementation by Ali Salloum: https://github.com/Alsaoudi-Salloum/ViT-Keras
> 5. Jax implementation by Ryan Reece: https://github.com/google/flax/tree/main/examples/vision_transformer
> 6. TensorFlow implementation with added Efficient Attention Module by GitHub user Vignesh Murali:
>    https://github.com/Holmesalbatross/ea-myelonet/blob/main/eamodel.py.

From the Google blog you can watch an animation that illustrates the simplicity of the model:

[animation](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-_mnVfmzvJWc/X8gMzhZ7SkI/AAAAAAAAG24/8gW2AHEoqUQrBwOqjhYB37A7OOjNyKuNgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/image1.gif)